How to increase the size of /boot partition?
Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS
Upgrade to 24.04 LTS fails due to lacking around 45M of space in /boot
# uname -r
6.7.6-060706-generic
# df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                         741M  3.0M  738M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/MediaServer-root  139G   16G  116G  13% /
tmpfs                         3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs                      128K   28K   96K  23% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/mapper/Movies-Movies      15T   14T  127G 100% /Movies
/dev/sdb2                     229M   97M  120M  45% /boot
/dev/sdb1                     190M  5.0M  185M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs                         741M   60K  741M   1% /run/user/0

# ls -l /boot
total 90816
-rw------- 1 root root  8374647 Feb 23 10:33 System.map-6.7.6-060706-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   284235 Feb 23 10:33 config-6.7.6-060706-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     2048 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Mar  8 10:41 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69021354 May  7 09:20 initrd.img-6.7.6-060706-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    12288 Mar  4  2013 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182800 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184476 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184980 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 14373376 Feb 23 10:33 vmlinuz-6.7.6-060706-generic

# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 149.05 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD1600AAJS-2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 03C201FA-E022-462F-A12F-79A579067E1C

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1    2048    391167    389120   190M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  391168    890879    499712   244M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  890880 312580095 311689216 148.6G Linux LVM

# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  200MB  199MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      200MB   456MB  256MB  ext2               msftdata
 3      456MB   160GB  160GB                     lvm

gparted shows a single partition and File System zfs.
# blkid /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: TYPE="zfs_member" PTUUID="03c201fa-e022-462f-a12f-79a579067e1c" PTTYPE="gpt"

zfs is not configured on this system.
# zpool status
-bash: zpool: command not found

How can i increase the space of the /boot partition?

Does this answer your question? Extend/resize boot partition

We normally suggest larger ESP as you may want other things, SystemD boot, update file for UEFI (if fwupdate not available, or other use). But if just for UEFI boot with grub, you can see you only use 3%, so could get by with a much smaller ESP. Not sure if enough more space for /boot or not. Changing LVM partition size is difficult. Often easier then to start over & restore from backup.

@oldfred Would like to go for resizing /boot/efi but gparted does not show any partitions on /dev/sdb. Could use parted to resize /boot/efi but don't see how i can add the free space to /boot.

Are you using live installer? You cannot edit mounted partitions and both ESP & /boot would be mounted in your install. Good backups always required.

Yes, live installer 22.04. As shown above, both fdisk and parted show the partitions but gparted shows a single partition (/dev/sdb) with filesystem zfs. Also blkid shows "zfs_member".

Went for a complete install of 24.04 from scratch after a fatal incident using wipefs.
Turns out that --force option overrules --no-act (dry run) ;)
